# Apple push notification badge number

Tags: objective-c, xcode, badge

I have developed server side application to maintain the badge number as increment or decrement after receiving new notification and delete after seeing notification it works fine.

But there is some problem in showing the badge, the actual scenario is - After getting new notification on device, I am click on cancel button then badge number shows correctly but after that I will open the application and close the application badge will be removed. That means I am not sending request to the server that notification was seen by me and now you can decrement the badge by one. Then also badge removed from app icon.

My question is that when we open the application then badge number automatically removed from (application) device? or it will shows as it is until we set to zero?

Answer (score 13):

It will show until you set it to zero and you can do it with the following code:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0]
```

EDIT: 
It is more common to set the badge number as you receive the notification, in either `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` or `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` methods of your `UIApplicationDelegate` class.

You can read more about it in the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the icon badge automatically use the following code.

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    NSLog(@"userInfo %@",userInfo);

    for (id key in userInfo) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }

    [application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"] intValue]];

    NSLog(@"Badge %d",[[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"] intValue]);

}
```

We also need to change the php file. So we can get the change the icon badge automatically

```
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
    'id' => '135',
    'badge' => 8
    );
```