# Showing and deleting number on badge depending upon the Apple Push Notifications

Tags: ios, ios6, apple-push-notifications, badge

I have an app where I am using apple push notifications. Now I need to show the badge number depending upon the notifications, and I also need to decrease the badge number accordingly.
I know this method is used for showing badge, but I am getting how to implement it.

```
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeNumer;
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your code inside this method to show badge number.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Comment: Ya i am doing it  but i am not getting how to increase and decrease the badge number.

Comment: Will this method get called when the app is not in background or foreground that means app is not launched yet?

Answer (score 0):

It will show until you set it to zero and you can do it with the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0]
```

It is more common to set the badge number as you receive the notification, in either application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: or application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: methods of your UIApplicationDelegate class.

You can read more about it in the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: How does it differ from below link. Just copy & paste. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424938/apple-push-notification-badge-number/6424962#6424962